# I got new questions NumPy dimension

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I have a question regarding Numpy dimension that is frequently used in Keras and many other applications

**Question 1**

what is the difference between shape=(10,1) and (10,)?

**Question 2**

what is 'None' in some applications with NumPy, 
ex) input_shape=(None, 32)
does it mean the specific size is not set yet?

**Question 3**

how should I interpret this: 
...axis=-1
how can an axis be set to -1 ?

Comment: `None` is not a valid `numpy` dimension.  Other packages like `tensorflow` do use it.

Comment: in Python, `-1` is commonly used to denote the last element or last dimension

Comment: `(10,1)` is a 2d array, `(10,)` 1d.  They can be reshaped to each other.  You'll see differences in display, indexing, broadcasting, etc.

Comment: About `input_shape=(None, 32)`, you may be referring to the `input_shape` parameter in Keras layers. In that case, it is a TensorFlow shape, it means each example in the batch has a first dimension of unspecified size and a second dimension of 32 elements (typically it represents sequence data). Unlike NumPy, in TensorFlow (non-eager mode, where tensors are symbolic) `None` can be used to indicate that the size of some tensor dimension is not fixed in advance.

Comment: @Jim Kim, If I have answered your question, can you please accept answer and up vote it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Answer: Array with shape (10000,) is a 1-Dimensional Array, where as Array with shape (10000,1) is a 2-Dimensional Array

```
import numpy as np

# Array with shape (10000,) is a 1-Dimensional Array
one=np.ones((10,))
print("1-Dimensional Array:\n",one)

#Array with shape (10000,1) is a 2-Dimensional Array.
two=np.ones((10,1)) 
print("2-Dimensional Array:\n",two)
```

Output:

```
1-Dimensional Array:
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

2-Dimensional Array:
 [[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

2) Answer:
None just adds a dimension to array object. You can either use "None" or numpy's "newaxis" to create the new dimension.

General Tip: You can also use None in place of np.newaxis

```
import numpy as np

#### Import the Fashion MNIST dataset
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

#Original Dimension
print(train_images.shape)

train_images1 = train_images[None,:,:,:]
#Add Dimension using None
print(train_images1.shape)

train_images2 = train_images[np.newaxis is None,:,:,:]
#Add dimension using np.newaxis
print(train_images2.shape)

#np.newaxis and none are same
np.newaxis is None
```

Output:

```
(60000, 28, 28)
(1, 60000, 28, 28)
(1, 60000, 28, 28)
True
```

3) Answer:
The axis parameter specifies the index of the new axis in the dimensions of the result. For example, if axis=0 it will be the first dimension and if axis=-1 it will be the last dimension.

```
# input array 
a = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3], [ -1, -2, -3]] ) 
print ("1st Input array : \n", a)  

b = np.array([[ 4, 5, 6], [ -4, -5, -6]] ) 
print ("2nd Input array : \n", b)  

# Stacking the two arrays along axis 0 
out1 = np.stack((a, b), axis = 0) 
print ("Output array along axis 0:\n ", out1) 

# Stacking the two arrays along axis 1 
out2 = np.stack((a, b), axis = 1) 
print ("Output array along axis 1:\n ", out2) 

# Stacking the two arrays along axis -1 
out3 = np.stack((a, b), axis = -1) 
print ("Output array along axis -1:\n ", out3)
```

Output:

```
1st Input array : 
 [[ 1  2  3]
 [-1 -2 -3]]

2nd Input array : 
 [[ 4  5  6]
 [-4 -5 -6]]

Output array along axis 0:
  [[[ 1  2  3]
  [-1 -2 -3]]

 [[ 4  5  6]
  [-4 -5 -6]]]

Output array along axis 1:
  [[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]]

 [[-1 -2 -3]
  [-4 -5 -6]]]

Output array along axis -1:
  [[[ 1  4]
  [ 2  5]
  [ 3  6]]

 [[-1 -4]
  [-2 -5]
  [-3 -6]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :=) so much helpful.. really appreciate your answers, so grateful!

Comment: @Jim Kim, If I have answered your question, can you please accept it and up vote it.Thanks.